# R github rendering js files to see googleVis html

Tags: javascript, r, github, knitr, googlevis

Using R, I would like to be able to render an `.html` or `.md` file (that has either been created via `knitr` or some other manner) that contains `googleVis` charts in a repo in github.

I was trying to follow the help file when running `?plot.gvis`, and I have tried pushing up the `gvisData.js` and `gvisFunctions.js` files into the repo and altered the html to reference these, but I have a feeling that I dont quite have the correct baseURL in order for github to be able to render it correctly.

Does anybody have a simple example of a URL that references Github that renders googleVis charts?

I have tried using this http://lamages.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/googlevis-tutorial-at-user2013.html but didn't see how it would work with github...

So using the example given in `?plot.gvis` this is what I tried

```
myChartID <- "mtnc"
baseURL <- "https://raw.github.com/USER/REPO"
wwwdir <- getwd() ## the working directory is the local directory of the repo


## Create a motion chart
M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year", chartid=myChartID)



## Write the data and functions into separate files:
cat(M$html$chart['jsData'], file=file.path(wwwdir, "gvisData.js"))
cat(M$html$chart[c('jsDrawChart', 'jsDisplayChart', 'jsChart')], 
                file=file.path(wwwdir, "gvisFunctions.js"))


## Create a html page with reference to the above
## JavaScript files 

html <- sprintf('
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="%s/gvisFunctions.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="%s/gvisData.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  displayChart%s()
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="%s" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ', baseURL, baseURL, myChartID, myChartID)

## Write html scaffold into a file
cat(html, file=file.path(wwwdir, paste("Chart", myChartID, ".html", sep="")))

### from this point I push up to the repo the following files 
### gvisData.js, gvsiFunctions.js and Chartmtnc.html

## Display the result via
URL <- paste(baseURL,"/Chart", myChartID, ".html", sep="")
browseURL(URL)
```

Any suggestions would be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating it unnecessarily. You just need to do one thing, when you are trying to use a `googleVis` chart in a `knitr` document, which is to set

```
options(gvis.plot.tag = 'chart')
```

You can see a published example [here](http://ramnathv.github.io/gvis_test/) and the source file can be found [here](http://github.com/ramnathv/gvis_test)

Comment: Thank you very simple! and just noticed you are the author of slidify! great package well done!